# Excel file encoding with french accents and special characters after an export from windows

Tags: python-3.x, excel, windows

I have been sent an excel file that wassaved in windows and that contains a lot of encoding replacements:

- \u2019 instead of '
- \u00e9 instead of é
- \x90m instead of É

Do you guys know an elegant way to deal with the issue ?
I am using python3 as a language

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the elegant part, I have compiled a list of replace:

```py
def fix_windows_encoding_accents(text: str) -> str:

    """
    Function to cleanup the text from a windows export of an excel file
    This problem is due to ascii encoding

    This function takes care of all the accents and special characters starting with xe or u

    :param text: text to parse
    :type text: str

    :return: parsed text
    :rtype: str
    """

    replace_dict = {
        # u punctuation
        "\\u00a0": " ",
        "\\u00ab": '"',
        "\\u00bb": '"',
        "\\u00b0": "°",
        "\\u00b7": "·",
        "\\u00b4": "'",
        "\\u00a8": '"',
        "\\u00a9": "©",
        "\\u263a\\ufe0f": "☺",
        "\\u00ae": "®",
        "\\u00b2": "²",
        "\\u00b3": "³",
        "\\u00b5": "µ",
        "\\u00b6": "¶",
        "\\u00b9": "¹",
        "\\u00bc": "¼",
        "\\u00bd": "½",
        "\\u00be": "¾",
        "\\u00bf": "¿",
        "\\u00a1": "¡",
        "\\u00a2": "¢",
        "\\u00a3": "£",
        "\\u00a4": "¤",
        "\\u00a5": "¥",
        "\\u00a6": "¦",
        "\\u00a7": "§",
        "\\u00a8": "¨",
        "\\u00aa": "ª",
        "\\u00ac": "¬",
        "\\u00ad": "­",
        "\\u2019": "'",
        "\\u2013": "-",
        "\\u201c": '"',
        "\\u201d": '"',
        "\\u2014": "-",
        "\\u2018": "'",
        "\\u2026": "...",
        # u emojis
        "\\u263a": "☺",
        "\\ufe0f": "",
        # u a
        "\\u00e0": "à",
        "\\u00e2": "â",
        "\\u00e4": "ä",
        "\\u00e6": "æ",
        # u c
        "\\u00e7": "ç",
        # u e
        "\\u00e9": "é",
        "\\u00ea": "ê",
        "\\u00eb": "ë",
        # u i
        "\\u00ee": "î",
        "\\u00ef": "ï",
        # u o
        "\\u00f4": "ô",
        "\\u00f6": "ö",
        "\\u0153": "œ",
        # u u
        "\\u00f9": "ù",
        "\\u00fb": "û",
        "\\u00fc": "ü",
        # u y
        "\\u00fd": "ÿ",
        # u A
        "\\u00c0": "À",
        "\\u00c2": "Â",
        "\\u00c4": "Ä",
        "\\u00c6": "Æ",
        # u C
        "\\u00c7": "Ç",
        # u E
        "\\u00c8": "È",
        "\\u00c9": "É",
        "\\u00ca": "Ê",
        "\\u00cb": "Ë",
        # u I
        "\\u00ce": "Î",
        "\\u00cf": "Ï",
        # u O
        "\\u00d4": "Ô",
        "\\u00d6": "Ö",
        "\\u0152": "Œ",
        # u U
        "\\u00d9": "Ù",
        "\\u00db": "Û",
        "\\u00dc": "Ü",
        # u emojis
        "\\U0001f635": "",
        "\\U0001f60d": "",
        "\\U0001f60e": "",
        "\\U0001f60f": "",
        "\\U0001f612": "",
        "\\U0001f613": "",
        "\\U0001f614": "",
        "\\U0001f923": "",
        "\\U0001f628": "",
        "\\U0001f62d": "",
        "\\U0001f62e": "",
        "\\U0001f62f": "",
        "\\U0001f630": "",
        "\\U0001f631": "",
        "\\U0001f632": "",
        "\\U0001f633": "",
        "\\U0001f634": "",
        "\\U0001f636": "",
        "\\U0001f637": "",
        "\\U0001f638": "",
        "\\U0001f639": "",
        "\\U0001f64f": "",
        "\\U0001f643": "",
        "\\U0001f605": "",
        "\\U0001f60a": "",
        # x punctuation
        "\\x80": "€",
        "\\x82": "‚",
        "\\x83": "ƒ",
        "\\x84": "„",
        "\\x85": "…",
        "\\x86": "†",
        "\\x87": "‡",
        "\\x88": "ˆ",
        "\\x89": "‰",
        "\\x8a": "Š",
        "\\x8b": "‹",
        "\\x8c": "Œ",
        "\\x8e": "Ž",
        "\\x91": "‘",
        "\\x92": "’",
        "\\x93": "“",
        "\\x94": "”",
        "\\x95": "•",
        "\\x96": "–",
        "\\x97": "—",
        "\\x98": "˜",
        "\\x99": "™",
        "\\x9a": "š",
        "\\x9b": "›",
        "\\x9c": "œ",
        "\\x9e": "ž",
        "\\x9f": "Ÿ",
        "\\xa1": "¡",
        "\\xa2": "¢",
        "\\xa3": "£",
        "\\xa4": "¤",
        "\\xa5": "¥",
        "\\xa6": "¦",
        "\\xa7": "§",
        "\\xa8": "¨",
        "\\xa9": "©",
        "\\xaa": "ª",
        "\\xab": "«",
        "\\xac": "¬",
        "\\xad": "­",
        "\\xae": "®",
        "\\xaf": "¯",
        "\\xb0": "°",
        "\\xb1": "±",
        "\\xb2": "²",
        "\\xb3": "³",
        "\\xb4": "´",
        "\\xb5": "µ",
        "\\xb6": "¶",
        "\\xb7": "·",
        "\\xb8": "¸",
        "\\xb9": "¹",
        "\\xba": "º",
        "\\xbb": "»",
        "\\xbc": "¼",
        "\\xbd": "½",
        "\\xbe": "¾",
        "\\xbf": "¿",
        "\\xd7": "×",
        "\\xf7": "÷",
        "\\x2d": "-",
        "\\x2f": "/",
        "\\x5c": "\\",
        "\\x5f": "_",
        "\\x60": "`",
        "\\x7b": "{",
        "\\x7c": "|",
        "\\x7d": "}",
        "\\x7e": "~",
        "\\x7f": "⌂",
        "\\x80": "Ç",
        "\\x81": "ü",
        "\\x82": "é",
        "\\x83": "â",
        "\\x84": "ä",
        "\\x85": "à",
        "\\x86": "å",
        "\\x87": "ç",
        "\\x88": "ê",
        "\\x89": "ë",
        "\\x8a": "è",
        "\\x8b": "ï",
        "\\x8c": "î",
        "\\x8d": "ì",
        "\\x8e": "Ä",
        "\\x8f": "Å",
        "\\x90": "É",
        "\\x91": "æ",
        "\\x92": "Æ",
        "\\x93": "ô",
        "\\x94": "ö",
        "\\x95": "ò",
        "\\x96": "û",
        "\\x97": "ù",
        "\\x98": "ÿ",
        "\\x99": "Ö",
        "\\x9a": "Ü",
        "\\x9b": "¢",
        "\\x9c": "£",
        "\\x9d": "¥",
        "\\x9e": "₧",
        "\\x9f": "ƒ",
        "\\xa0": "á",
        "\\xa1": "í",
        "\\xa2": "ó",
        "\\xa3": "ú",
        "\\xa4": "ñ",
        "\\xa5": "Ñ",
        "\\xa6": "ª",
        "\\xa7": "º",
        "\\xa8": "¿",
        "\\xa9": "⌐",
        "\\xaa": "¬",
        "\\xab": "½",
        "\\xab": '"',
        "\\xbb": '"',
        # x a
        "\\xe0": "à",
        "\\xe2": "â",
        "\\xe4": "ä",
        "\\xe6": "æ",
        # x c
        "\\xc7": "ç",
        "\\xe7": "ç",
        # x e
        "\\xe9": "é",
        "\\xe8": "è",
        "\\xe9": "é",
        "\\xea": "ê",
        "\\xeb": "ë",
        "\\xe9": "é",
        # x i
        "\\xee": "î",
        "\\xef": "ï",
        # x o
        "\\xf4": "ô",
        "\\xf6": "ö",
        "\\x9c": "œ",
        # x u
        "\\xf9": "ù",
        "\\xfb": "û",
        "\\xfc": "ü",
        # x y
        "\\xfd": "ÿ",
        # x A
        "\\xc0": "À",
        "\\xc2": "Â",
        "\\xc4": "Ä",
        "\\xc6": "Æ",
        # x C
        "\\xc7": "Ç",
        # x E
        "\\xc9": "É",
        "\\xca": "Ê",
        "\\xcb": "Ë",
        # x I
        "\\xce": "Î",
        "\\xcf": "Ï",
        # x O
        "\\xd4": "Ô",
        "\\xd6": "Ö",
        "\\x8c": "Œ",
        # x U
        "\\xd9": "Ù",
        "\\xdb": "Û",
        "\\xdc": "Ü",
    }

    for k, v in replace_dict.items():

        text = text.replace(k, v)

    return text
```

It is probably not exaustive, but it should take care of most of the errors in latin languages. Please let me know if any replacement is inaccurate, I will change them.